# preg_match_all data from other site

Tags: php, preg-match

f.e we have tr,td like this and i want use preg_match_all to select some data

```
<tr data-tag="tagid1" class="role-odd" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">pos</td>
    <td class="member_name" data-tag="tagid1">nick1</td>
    <td>rank1</td>
    <td>tagid2</td>
    <td class="right aligned">points</td>
    <td class="right aligned">lvl</td>
    <td data-sort="points">
        <img class="ui mini image" src="link" alt="desc">
    </td>
    <td class="right aligned" data-sort="points2">points2</td>
    <td class="right aligned" data-sort="points3">points3</td>
    <td>
        <div class="">
            <input id="compare-checkbox-tagid1" class="compareme" data-tag="tagid1" data-name="nick" type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr data-tag="tagid2" class="role-even" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">pos</td>
    <td class="member_name" data-tag="tagid2">nick2</td>
    <td>rank2</td>
    <td>tagid2</td>
    <td class="right aligned">points</td>
    <td class="right aligned">lvl</td>
    <td data-sort="points">
        <img class="ui mini image" src="link">
    </td>
    <td class="right aligned" data-sort="points">points2</td>
    <td class="right aligned" data-sort="points3">points3</td>
    <td>
        <div class="">
            <input id="compare-checkbox-tagid2" class="compareme" data-tag="tagid2" data-name="nick" type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

if i use the following code

```
preg_match_all('#<tr[^>]+>(.+?)</tr>#ims',$out,$top);
```

$top contains all `trs`, but i don't need all data, i want the following data: `pos,nick,rank,tagid,points,lvl,points2,points3`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: **NEVER** parse html with regex. Use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want get all contents from `<td>` ?
You can try regular `#<td.*?>(.*)<\/td>#`